# Google Maps API to calculate route time

Tags: vb.net, winforms, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

sorry in advance for not having any code written yet to share but I have been searching around for quite some time yet and haven't been able to find a good source or solution. I am trying to figure out if it is possible for me to incorporate a google maps api that will calculate an estimated travel time between two locations that I can return to the user in a Windows Form.

The starting location and destination location will be entered into two separate textbox's the outcome of this is, either when a button is clicked, or once the form that the information is entered into is saved, an estimated travel time will be calculated and shown in a grid or textbox. I have seen a few articles that show how to calculate the distance and I have thought about trying to calculate a really rough estimated time by calculating the distance and dividing it by a constant for the speed but I would really like to know if I can use google's application of this instead.

Comment: How are the users entering the locations? with Lat/Long or Zip(Postal) code? Are you trying to calculate the "as the crow flies" shortest distance or the road route?

Comment: They will be entering the address (ex. 232 cherry hill rd, New York, New York), and trying to calculate the road route for probably the shortest distance to drive to the destination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Documentation :**

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/

**You have to prepare url string using this template :**

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin={0}&destination={1}&sensor={2}&language={3}{4}{5}{6}

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=232+cherry+hill+rd,+New+York&destination=22+cherry+hill+rd,+New+York&sensor=false&language=en&avoid=highways&avoid=tolls&units=imperial

**Then perform request :**

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Accept = requestAccept;

using(HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
         {
            using(Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
               using(StreamReader read = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
               {
                  ret = read.ReadToEnd();
               }
            }
            response.Close();
         }
```

**And in ret you get xml response :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DirectionsResponse>
 <status>OK</status>
 <route>
  <summary>Cherry Hill Rd</summary>
  <leg>
   <step>
    <travel_mode>DRIVING</travel_mode>
    <start_location>
     <lat>41.8542652</lat>
     <lng>-74.1999310</lng>
    </start_location>
    <end_location>
     <lat>41.8506910</lat>
     <lng>-74.1990648</lng>
    </end_location>
    <polyline>
     <points>etm~Fpd{cM\BjBVbB?x@DrBd@R?TCRK^YvA}AtAgAb@e@</points>
    </polyline>
    <duration>
     <value>31</value>
     <text>1 min</text>
    </duration>
    <html_instructions>Head &lt;b&gt;south&lt;/b&gt; on &lt;b&gt;Cherry Hill Rd&lt;/b&gt; toward &lt;b&gt;Hornbeck Rd&lt;/b&gt;</html_instructions>
    <distance>
     <value>432</value>
     <text>0.3 mi</text>
    </distance>
   </step>
   <duration>
    <value>31</value>
    <text>1 min</text>
   </duration>
   <distance>
    <value>432</value>
    <text>0.3 mi</text>
   </distance>
   <start_location>
    <lat>41.8542652</lat>
    <lng>-74.1999310</lng>
   </start_location>
   <end_location>
    <lat>41.8506910</lat>
    <lng>-74.1990648</lng>
   </end_location>
   <start_address>232 Cherry Hill Road, Accord, NY 12404, USA</start_address>
   <end_address>22 Cherry Hill Road, Accord, NY 12404, USA</end_address>
  </leg>
  <copyrights>Map data ©2015 Google</copyrights>
  <overview_polyline>
   <points>etm~Fpd{cMhCZbB?x@DrBd@R?TCRK^YvA}AtAgAb@e@</points>
  </overview_polyline>
  <bounds>
   <southwest>
    <lat>41.8506910</lat>
    <lng>-74.2002909</lng>
   </southwest>
   <northeast>
    <lat>41.8542652</lat>
    <lng>-74.1990648</lng>
   </northeast>
  </bounds>
 </route>
</DirectionsResponse>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm guessing that I will be able to find on google's api page the different variables to concatenate to my url string right?

Comment: yes, try CTRL+F and find "var name" on web page, but I recommend you read all doc (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions) for better understanding this part api.

Comment: You sir... are a hero. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the travel distance and travel time for multiple origins and destinations, use the [Distance Matrix service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix) in the Google Maps JavaScript API or [Google Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/) (a web service)